# How to remove all the element which equal to certain value in an array swift 4?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift4

**I have a `NSObject` class look like this:**

```
class MyItem : NSObject {

    var id: Int
    var name: String

    //other init code here
 }
```

**So the array I define like this**

```
var myItem = [MyItem]()
```

**Here is the sample of my array:**

```
{
"id" : 2
"name" : "Ali"

"id" : 3
"name" : "janice"

"id" : 2
"name" : "Ali"

"id" : 5
"name" : "tupac"

"id" : 2
"name" : "Ali"

"id" : 8
"name" : "William"

"id" : 2
"name" : "Ali"  
}
```

**What I want to do is**,write a function to remove all the element with the `id` which is equal to `2`,so the array just left the element with `id` equal to `[3,5,8]`.

**I tried this code**,but it just remove 1 element only but I want to remove all four element with `id` = 2

```
func removeId(id : Int){
  //find the index 1st
   guard let foundIndex = myItem.index(where: { $0.id == id }) else { return }
   myItem.remove(at: foundIndex)
}
```

Somebody please help,Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter`:

```
func removeId(id: Int) {
   myItem = myItem.filter { $0.id != id }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use filter() predicate to filter your array as show below**

```
var myArray = ["Hello","Coding","World"]

myArray = myArray.filter{$0 != "Hello"}

print(myArray)   // "[Coding, World]"
```